# Meaning of 'made them out to be'

Tags: meaning

> Michelson-Morley experiments weren't the failure MIT **made them out to be**,  just as Cold Fusion wasn't the failure MIT made it out to be

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means "represented them as":

> MichelsonMorley experiments weren't the failure MIT [represented them as] ...

To "make something out to be" something else is to portray it in a certain light. If my comments *make you out to be a great guy* that means I am saying good things about you. If they *make you out to be a jerk* that means I'm not being so complimentary.